# What's wrong with my "sum event" in reactive-banana?

Tags: haskell, reactive-banana

I'm learning reactive-banana and intending to use it in a server-side app. I have some background in RxJs, so I'm used to combining Events with different combinators there. So I started with simple event combinator examples. I tried to make a simple reactive-banana example that would combine two integer events into a sum event. I understand that to be able to combine values from different events, I have to make them into Behaviors first, the do the combination and finally make that into a new event. This is how I did it:

```
-- Behaviors from Events e1, e2
let b1 = stepper 0 e1 :: Behavior Int
let b2 = stepper 0 e2 :: Behavior Int

-- Sum Behavior
let sumB = (+) <$> b1 <*> b2
-- Back to Event
let sumE = sumB <@ (e1 `union` e2)
```

Full runnable example can be found in [Gist 1594917](https://gist.github.com/1594917).

The problem here is that while the sumE event is correctly triggered when a new value appears in one of the events (e1, e2), it contains a stale value. This is apparently due to how stepper works (the value of the behavior changes "slightly after" the event occurrences). I tried replacing Behavior with Discrete, with the same result.

Is there a simple way to make this kind of event combinators work correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your diagnosis is exactly correct.  Here are two options: you can work back to an Event from Discrete via `changes`, or you can create accumulating events.

Working back from Discrete is probably simpler (and is what I would recommend). Just do

```
-- Discretes from Events e1, e2
let d1 = stepperD 0 e1 :: Discrete Int
let d2 = stepperD 0 e2 :: Discrete Int

-- Sum Discrete
let sumD = (+) <$> d1 <*> d2
-- Back to Event
let sumE = changes sumD
```

Now `sumE` will always update when `e1` or `e2` changes.

The alternative uses only Events, by converting incoming events into accumulating functions.  It sounds complex, but the code is fairly simple.

```
--convert each input into an accumulating tuple
let e1' = (\l (_,r) -> (l,r)) <$> e1
let e2' = (\r (l,_) -> (l,r)) <$> e2

let sumE = uncurry (+) <$> accumE (0,0) (e1' `union` e2')
```

Comment: Just to clarify: there is no delay in either of your approaches, the `sumE` events will occur simultaneously with `e1` and `e2`.

Comment: Thanks, @HeinrichApfelmus.  I've edited my answer to hopefully be more clear.